# Multiple styleClass for a VF component

Tags: visualforce, styleclass

Is there a way to put in multiple style classes? I want to take the btn class and add on a custom style class on my page called additionalStyle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just treat it just like a normal html `class` attribute and add multiple classes with a space in between...

Html Button:

```
<button class="style1 style2">Something</button>
```

Visualforce CommandButton:

```
<apex:commandButton styleClass="style1 style2" action="{!something}" value="Something" />
```