# Visualforce Number field validation gotchas?

Tags: visualforce, validation

I have a visualforce form with an input field linked to a number field on a salesforce object.

Problem - I've had a number of users report "not a number" errors when trying to fill in this form - I can't duplicate this error, and since the validation occurs automatically prior to submission to the controller I don't have any easy way of checking what the users are putting in.

The users swear that they are actually putting numbers in...

I also can't spot exactly what the standard validation criteria are for a number field in salesforce. Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this? Are there some obscure characters that might be causing this? I've tried with a variety of different number characters, and I can't seem to generate this error! Is anyone aware of any common "gotchas" for number fields?

Code:

```
<div class="form-group row">
       <div class="col-sm-6 number-input">
           <label>Weight(in {! weightUnit}) :</label>
           <apex:inputField styleClass="number-input" value="{!sweety.weight__c}" 
                            styleclass="form-control" required="true" />
       </div>
</div>
<apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" styleclass="btn btn-primary btn-lg"/>
```

Comment: It may help if you share your code. There isn't a lot to go off right now, and I'm not aware of any "gotchas", so a look into the code would probably be the best bet.

Comment: Sure - I shall do that

Comment: I know you said that people swear they are putting in numbers, but maybe there are spaces or other things being inputted as well. Since it is supposed to be a number field, you should add type="number" to ensure that Users can ONLY enter number values (and not text or spaces). Take a look here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputField.htm

Comment: That's just for step 1. If they are still getting that error after that, then it would be time for the next steps (check if the value is being transformed at some point from a number to a non-number value, etc...)

Comment: N.B. - see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/42063/multiple-styleclass-for-a-vf-component for alternate way to define two styleclasses per VF component

Comment: Actually, @cropredy , the two don't seem to be equivalent - if you define both classes within the one styleClass attribute, both classes get applied to the encompassing div - whereas with the code I currently have, 'number-input' gets applied to the encompassing div, while 'form-control' gets applied to the input element itself.

Comment: interesting ....